# RegEx match for the following characters A-Z , a-z , 0-9 , ? ! $ , '.

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7.1

I want the user to allow to type in the TextBox only for the following characters A-Z , a-z , 0-9 ,  ? ! $ , '. in the Silverlight Windows Phone... Can we achieve this through RegEx expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if only you need a regular expression, then:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\?\!\$,\.]*$/
```

Comment: How can i block the user to type other than this characters in TextBox ?

Comment: Please consult this article: http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1813-perform-filter-textbox-silverlight.aspx It doesn't use RegEx though. You need to do the other way round: check if passed PlatformKeyCode is allowed. Please let me know if you run into any trouble with this. For a list of possible Key values plese consult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

RegEx returns NULL value if a string does not match the given criteria.
Instead of using RegEx,you have to handle key Event on keyUp event.

```
function validate()
{
var keyCode=event.keyCode;
if((keyCode>=48 && keyCode<=57) && (keyCode>=65 && keyCode<=90)){

   //if keyCode is in 0-9,a-z ....do whatever you want...

}else{
    //else it will terminate the last character from text box
   var x =document.getElementById("inp");
   x.value=x.value.substring(0,x.value.length-1);
}
}

<input type="text" id="inp" onkeyup="validate()" />
```